# Why the composition factors are all isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension $1$ and suppose that $\mathfrak p$ is a nonzero prime of $A$.

Now let $M$ be an Artinian $A_{\mathfrak p}$-Module and suppose that
$${0}\subset M_1\subset\ldots\subset M_n=M$$
is its composition series.

> Why is it true that each quotient $M_{j+1}/M_j$ is isomorphic to
>   $A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$ (for any $j$)?

Comment: Do you know the simple modules over a local ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of a composition series, each quotient $M_{j+1}/M_j$ is a simple $A_\mathfrak{p}$-module, i.e. a module of the form $A_{\mathfrak{p}}/I$ for some maximal ideal $I$ of $A_\mathfrak{p}$.  But the only maximal ideal of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$, so every $M_{j+1}/M_j$ must be isomorphic to $A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$.